# What's the difference between "as much as I *would pay,* if ..." and "as much as I *paid*, if..." in these conditional sentences?

Tags: conditionals

I am not sure what to use "would pay" or "paid" in this sentence. What do you think? Both seems correct.

1 In the US I would pay for it three times as much **as I would pay** for it if I were in Germany.

2 In the US I would pay for it three times as much **as I paid** for it if I were in Germany.

3 In the US I would pay for it three times as much **as if I would pay** for it if I were in Germany.

4 In the US I would pay for it three times as much **as if I paid** for it if I were in Germany.

Comment: Did you buy it in Germany (either once or often), or is that purely hypothetical? None of those are very idiomatic, but you should establish what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a hypothetical situation - imagining buying the same thing in two different countries - so *would pay* is more appropriate.

However, a native speaker would probably say

> In the US, I would pay three times as much for it as I would in Germany.